# How do I setup an array in C++ with a constant as the max size allowed?

Tags: c++

```
class grades
{
private:
   char *grade;
   string course[20];
   int numCourse;
public:
   grades();
   bool setGrade(char *gradeIn);
   bool setCourse(char *nameIn);

};
```

So that's my class declaration. I want to set a constant number instead of 20 in the array declaration. How would I go about doing that? I have tried static const but the problem is that every time the class returns an error saying out of scope.

Comment: Use a vector with the `resize` function.

Comment: "20" *is* a "constant number". ;)

Comment: You really need to post the unsuccessful code.

Comment: I recommend that you use `std::vector`.

Comment: Why not `std::array`?

Comment: Not to mention `std::string` instead of that character pointer. Unless it's actually pointing to one character for whatever reason. That's the problem with them.

Comment: #define GRADES_ARRAY_SIZE 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
class grades
{
private:
   char *grade;
   static const int MAX_COURSES = 20;
   string course[MAX_COURSES];
   int numCourse;
public:
   grades();
   bool setGrade(char *gradeIn);
   bool setCourse(char *nameIn);

};
```

Comment: I'd reformulate this to seem more like an actual answer.

Comment: thanks! i forgot the file compiled from top to bottom. I had the static const declaration in the public section below the array declaration

Comment: By the way, having the `MAX_COURSES` elsewhere in the class should not be a problem either, even if it's "below" where it's used.

Answer (score 1):

Use a #define.  Old school, but it still works.

or...  declare a

```
 const int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 20
```

in a namespace (i.e. outside of the class).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. We're using C++ here.

Comment: I was under the impression that constants are NOT meant to be all capitals, and that that was the correct way to name macros.